# Отключение определённой системной библиотеки для программы

Tags: linux, library, libc

У меня такая проблема:

Есть бинарный файл `TheBinary`

Есть директория с библиотеками `./lib`

Запускаю программу так `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./lib ./TheBianry`

Проблема с `libc.so.6`, если она не лежит в `./lib`, то ошибка такая:

```
./TheBianry: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.25' not found (required by ./lib/libgnutls.so.30)
./TheBianry: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.22' not found (required by ./lib/libgnutls.so.30)
```

Если же `libc.so.6` лежит в `./lib`, то вывод такой:

```
./TheBianry: relocation error: ./lib/libc.so.6: symbol _dl_exception_create, version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined in file ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 with link time reference
```

Я прочитал, что нужно заменить старый файл новым. Обновить систему не могу, так как это сервер. Получить рут уже пытался, бесполезно. Надеюсь на вашу помощь, скорее всего, надо просто запретить использывать `/lib64/libc.so.6` и оставить только `./lib/libc.so.6`. Подскажите как это сделать, буду очень благодарен.

Comment: Проблемы с libc подменоной библиотек не решатся. Проще обновить систему до следующего релиза (в котором новое апи glibc) путем смены сервера. 

Попробуйте найти TheBianry для вашей glibc. Например достать из пакета от Centos.

Comment: eri, вот и пытаюсь это сделать, не могу найти ничего. И программа не из репозиториев.

Comment: эх, видимо не решится моя проблема( Везде банят

Comment: тогда пишите автору чтоб он собрал её в manylinux или для вашей версии

Comment: eri, но для майнера обязательна новая libc как я понимаю

Comment: не обязательна.

Comment: я на своём пк с такой же проблемой сталкивался, нужно было просто обновиться

Comment: все варианты в овете. я пробовал подсовывать glibc для своей программы - не вышло.

Comment: Вам надо приложить вывод `file ...` и `ldd ...` на файлы самой программы и проблемной библиотеки. И ещё вывод `ls -lR ./lib`.

Comment: 0andriy, вот посмотрите https://www.geany.org/p/2tFTy/

Comment: Это WSL что ли? У вас все символические ссылки битые, и права не выставлены. Ну да ладно, вы изучили вывод `ldd`? Там написано, откуда берётся *libc.so.6*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Повышение версии glibc без обновления дистрибутива врятли получится.
Понижение версии можно сделать через chroot, но также нужны права root.

Если доступны исходники - соберите сами на виртуалке с нужной версией.

Попробуйте найти TheBianry для вашей glibc.
Пишите автору чтоб он собрал её в manylinux.
Можно попросить объектный файл и слинковать его вручную.

Comment: Повышение — запросто, всё-таки обратную совместимость удерживают. Суперпользователь не нужен. Можно просто бинарные файлы подложить, тоже будет работать.

Comment: @0andriy как ни старался - libc подложить не получилось.

Comment: попробую ещё раз как-нибудь)